# Quantitative method to determine necessary and sufficient causes

Tags: regression, qualitative

I am attending a qualitative methods conference in social science, and one of the speaker argues the following.

In the two graphs below, a researcher using regression would see two regression lines with identical slopes and different intercept -- thus, he would not detect any difference.

In contrast, for a qualitative researcher, the first graph is a perfect case of X being a necessary condition for Y (i.e. Y < X, or Y is limited by X), while the second graph is a perfect case of X being a sufficient condition for Y (i.e. Y > X, or X guarantees a minimum level of Y).

[image]

Link to [the article making the argument](http://cps.sagepub.com/cgi/doi/10.1177/0010414012466376).

Implicitly, the speaker is saying that regression cannot make the distinction that qualitative researchers can. Is this convincing to you? Is there quantitative tool to derive the necessary / sufficient distinction from this bivariate data?

Comment: This is nearly exact the same question you asked [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104404/using-regression-to-prove-that-x-is-a-necessary-condition-condition-for-y?rq=1) a few days ago, and there has been an answer you accepted. I also support @whuber's argument posted there: "The risk here might be that you appear to describe a procedure that hides the extremely simple nature of the analysis that you are proposing. When I read words like "prove," "logical," "necessity," and "causes" in the question I expect the results to be misinterpreted."

Comment: I asked this question again with more details because I still feel unresolved and do not want to open up an old question. The analysis won't be simple if the DGP is something like: $Fire = I[I(Fuel > c_1, Spark > c_2) + I(Fuel > c_3, Lightning > c_4) > 0]$, in which `I()` is an indicator function and all $c_*$ are threshold constants. Fuel is a necessary condition to Fire -- that can be detected by a simple graph. But with a lot of potential variables, we can't graph everything. I'm asking about what to do in that case.